# Onclick of link POST data to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, input

I know this type of question is asked a lot, I've seen quite a few, but none of them seem to answer what I am trying to do, even enough to get me started. I have very little understanding of jQuery, I haven't quite picked it all up (got PHP, though). I want to onclick() of my  element as shown below:

```
<form name="cleartask1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="taskid" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class='icheck-me' name="check1" data-skin="square" data-color="blue">
</form>
```

Submit data to a file, we'll say, for this example post.php, but I need it to send the value of all of the form elements when checked (the default for a checkbox) to the post.php file. The post.php file will then pull the data from what was posted from the form. Would I call it in a way as below?

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['taskid'];
?>
```

How would I post that to the post.php file? If this doesn't make sense please tell me and I will definitely explain in greater detail. Pretty much I want to post form data on the click of a check box for that specific form.

Notice: The form name and checkbox name are the same to group them together, these tasks will be listed from a MySQL database so grouping them ensures that I submit to the correct one.

Please let me know if you can help, or if you need further information.

**UPDATE: I do need to submit this without reloading as this is a live task list, so submitting this without reloading would be best. If it's possible could someone provide an example of jQuery's Ajax to use in order to complete this?**

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean something like this? you can use `jQuery.submit()`

```
$(".icheck-me").click(function(){

       $("form[name='cleartask1']").submit();
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

> How do I submit the form to another page without reloading, though?
>   That probably would of made more sense to ask. :) Sorry

as you want to make a post without reloading the page you need to use AJAX 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

and Jquery has a simple way for doing AJAX Request

it would be something like this

```
$(".icheck-me").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<address to your page where you want to send your data>",
         data: { taskid: $("input[type='taskid']").val()
                }
          success:function(rsp){
            //do anything you want after a successful ajax request
          }
      });
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Well we want to help you that much but please have a time to study something about ajax first and the the ajax things in jquery.. then if you have find some difficulties of understanding it then ask here again and post what you have done so far =)

Comment: How do I submit the form to another page without reloading, though? That probably would of made more sense to ask. :) Sorry..

Comment: well you need to use ajax.. please define your need of non reloading submit in your question

Comment: @Mahan I have Re-worded the question in the UPDATE area.